# Relating argument type and return type without generics (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

Say I have 6 interfaces

- A1, A2
- B1, B2
- C1, C2

I want to write a function which takes one of A1, B1 and C1; returns one of A2, B2 and C2 such that the relation is kept. (A1 => A2, B1=>B2, C1=>C2)

I cannot use generics in my case.

---

Here is the real scenario.

I have the interfaces below

- interface MultipleChoiceQuestion extends Question
- interface DropdownQuestion extends Question
- interface InputQuestion extends Question

**

- interface MultipleChoiceResponse extends Response
- interface DropdownResponse extends Response
- interface InputResponse extends Response

**

- interface MultipleChoiceResult extends Result
- interface DropdownResult extends Result
- interface InputResult extends Result

Now, I need a function which takes a Question and a Response, and returns a Result. However I do not want to loose types

Comment: write different methods for each.

Comment: [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a function which takes one of A1, B1 and C1; returns one of A2, B2 and C2 such that the relation is kept. (A1 => A2, B1=>B2, C1=>C2)

Simple function [overloading](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/functions.html#overloading):

```
function foo(a: A1): A2;
function foo(a: B1): B2;
function foo(a: C1): C2;
function foo(a: A1 | B1 | C1): A2 | B2 | C2 {
  //  implement
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, given an argument of type A1, this function can return B2. That's what I want to restrict. Given A1, the return type must be A2. typeof foo(A1) == A2